# Jupyter R-Notebook Docker Images don't seem to include an R kernal

Tags: r, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, or my expectation is incorrect.

I've tried using multiple tagged version of the [Jupyter/r-notebook images](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/r-notebook/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) on dockerhub.  None seem to include an R kernel for Jupyter.  R does seem to be installed in the OS, but I'd like to create a Jupyter notebook that runs R code.

The documentation [here](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html#jupyter-r-notebook) seems to clearly indicate the [IRkernel](https://irkernel.github.io/) is included in the image.

The [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/r-notebook/Dockerfile) used to create the image seems to install `IRkernel`.

Do I need to do something to enable the IRkernel?

[image]

Comment: There is a bug report on this one here: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/1447

Comment: Life moves fast ... I'd entered an issue too.  Looks like they closed the issue you noted in favor of mine.  This seems to just be a bug.  I'll keep this open and reference the fix when provided.